# CSS background image not filling completely + JavaScript error handler

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with 2 things:

1. I don't know how to fix this CSS background issue. There's the code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("https://puzzenti.github.io/images/bg_test.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

When I open the dark grey div you see in the screenshot, the background doesn't fill the entire body.

[image: This is the issue]

2. I need 2 error handlers for a script in the same page. This is the script:

```js
function getMod() {
   var modName = document.getElementById('myInput').value
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (req.readyState === 4) {
           var response = req.responseText;
           var json = JSON.parse(response);

           var modID = String(json['data'][0]['mod_id']);
           var modName2 = String(json['data'][0]['mod_name']);
           var modAuthor = String(json['data'][0]['creatorname']);
           var modLikes = String(json['data'][0]['mod_votes']);
           var modUpdates = String(json['data'][0]['mod_updatecounter']);

           var modThumb = String("https://krunker-user-assets.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/md" + modID + "/thumb.png");
           var modDownload = String("https://krunker-user-assets.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/md" + modID + "/mod.zip");

           document.getElementById("modThumb").src=modThumb;
           document.getElementById("modName").innerHTML = String(modName2);
           document.getElementById("modAuthor").innerHTML = String(modAuthor);
           document.getElementById("modLikes").innerHTML = String(modLikes);
           document.getElementById("modUpdates").innerHTML = String(modUpdates);
           document.getElementById("infoContainer").style.display = "block";
           document.getElementById("downloadBtn").style.display = "block";

           var myBtn = document.getElementById('downloadBtn');

           myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
             window.location.href = modDownload;
           });
       }

       if (modName === "") {
           document.getElementById("modThumb").src="https://puzzenti.github.io/images/placeholder.png";
           document.getElementById("modName").innerHTML = "";
           document.getElementById("modAuthor").innerHTML = "";
           document.getElementById("modLikes").innerHTML = "";
           document.getElementById("modUpdates").innerHTML = "";
           document.getElementById("infoContainer").style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById("downloadBtn").style.display = "none";
       }
};

req.open('GET', String("https://api.krunker.io/webhooks/general/mods/search?val=" + modName));
req.send(null);
}
```

The first error handler it's **if (modName === "")** and it already works. What I want to do is to do the same thing as the first one but only if **modID** doesn't exist. The problem is that the website the script reads doesn't provide the **modID** string if the **modName** doesn't exist in their website.

**Example**:

Existing mod name:

```
{"index":3,"type":"mod","data":[{"mod_id":40959,"mod_name":"NuKl3Ar","creatorname":"NuKl3Ar_Alt","mod_description":"","mod_votes":3,"mod_url":"ua","mod_date":"2021-08-12T09:35:01.000Z","mod_info":"{\"t\":1}","mod_updatecounter":7}]}
```

Not existing mod name:

```
{"index":3,"type":"mod","data":[]}
```

As you can see there's no mod data, and I want to make an error handler for it.

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time, i.e. create two different questions for this

Comment: @NuKl3Ar- This may helpful to you :  [Background Size from W3 Schools - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: @KusalDarshana thx it worked for background-size: auto

Answer (score 0):

concerning question 1: You should apply `height: 100%` to `body` and `html` to achieve a minimum height for the body which is at least as high as the viewport/window.

Comment: I wrote about height, not width.